# How to Embed the perl interpreter in a C# Program

Tags: c#, perl, interop, dllimport

I realize that I have to `DllImport` the perlembed methods

```
perl_parse
perl_alloc
perl_free
```

etc.,

But not sure how to marhsall the function arguments for using it with `DLLImport` especially with `perl_parse` method.

I also realize that a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1196620/242888) already exists   which is almost there but still the OP has solved by created a C wrapper and then using it in C#.

He says that he was not able to DLLimport PERL_SYS_INIT3.

So my question is how to properly wrap them using only C# and use it?

Comment: Could you tell what you have tried?

Comment: Particular distribution?  ActiveState, Strawberry?

Comment: The one I tried with was with Active State and I primarily consulted the perlembed doc

Comment: discussion here may be useful: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=530344

Comment: Look here may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056275/embedding-perl-interpreter

Answer (score 2):

Look at this; I hope it will help (it was called in early version)

I got this from here ([perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=530344))

To embed a Perl interpreter in a C# program, add a reference to the COM object "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" and write code like this:

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass Interpreter;
Interpreter = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass();
Interpreter.Language = @"PerlScript";
string Program = @"reverse 'abcde'";
string Results = (string)Interpreter.Eval(Program);
```

The above is equivalent to the following Perl script, which embeds a Perl interpreter within a Perl interpreter:

```
use Win32::OLE;
my $Interpreter;
$Interpreter = Win32::OLE->new('ScriptControl');
$Interpreter->{Language} = 'PerlScript';
my $Program = "reverse 'abcde'";
my $Results = $Interpreter->Eval($Program);
```

Comment: That will work only if you have Active State Perl installed with the PerlScript feature. If you have a different Perl (e.g. you compiled Perl from source) you don't have PerlScript installed in the system.